# several with and a function inside with several wheres, how to do it

Tags: laravel

I have several tables with relationship.
There's only one that's giving work, it's the order_item_subitems table.
The order_item table, save the group id and order id.
I need to check the group id and check the order id, so I don't get sub-items of products that have nothing to do with that group.

There are 3 groups, each group has its products and can have a product for the 3 groups or for a single group.

My problem is to bring the information after registration. It brings values ​​for products in group b, for example, which were not even registered with a value in that order.

I just explained, but the focus here is.
How do I make several wheres work in this query?

```
$groups = GroupProduct::where('status', 1);
$groups = $groups->with(['groupProductProduct.product.items.orderitems' => function($query) use ($id) {
      $query->where([['order_items.order_id', $id], ['order_items.group_product_id', 'group_product_products.group_product_id']]);
}]);
$groups = $groups->get();
```

Comment: kindly add some info about your models structures and relationships